# How to use greyscale color in PIL's putpixel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I need a function that creates the whitest value for 0 and the blackest value for 1 (all other are, like 0.5, are some tone of grey) to put in `putpixel` but I have no idea how to do it.

```
value = Greyscale(0.5) #or any other in the range of 0 and 1.
Image.putpixel((X, Y), (value))
```

How can I implement this? Or is there already a function for that? I searched the docs but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: If your image is grayscale mode, you can put any value from 0 to 255 in it and it will have the respective brightness ranging from black (0) to white (255). If your Image is in color mode, I'm not sure if you can just put in the grayscale value. If you can't, you can just set the R, G and B components to be the same value and it will be gray.

Comment: Forget `putpixel()` as it is seriously slow. What are you actually trying to do? Make an image where every pixel is mid-grey? Make an image where every pixel is white? Make an image where every pixel is a random shade of grey?

Comment: No, no. I am trying to visualize modular arithmetic operations. As if done in, [here](https://maxwelldemon.com/2011/11/20/22-1-patterns-in-modular-arithmetic/). But i finished my job now. Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the bit depth of the L type image the values range from 0 to 255  with 8 bit depth.

For 8 bit depth the function is like:

```
def inverted_grayscale(v): 
    return int((1 - v) * 255)
```